# Problem regarding tag question

Tags: grammar

It is man who is the best of all creations,_ ?

Here, I think the tag should be "isn't he". But my teacher is suggesting otherwise. He is suggesting it to be "aren't they ". So, which one's the correct one?

Comment: Neither. Correct: *It is man who is the best of all creations, isn't it?* or *Man is the best of all creations, isn't he?* or *Men are the best of all creations, aren't they?*

Answer (score 1):

"It is man ..., isn't it"...The statement uses the dummy pronoun, and the verb "is" so the tag follows.

But tag questions are part of conversational speech. They are a way for one person to check that the other person understands and agrees.  But the sentence is formal and philosophical. Not something you would say while chatting.

The combination of "high speech" and "low speech" is comical, an example of *bathos*.

If you're not being funny.  Don't use a tag question at all!